# C#- Placing an edit button on the side of an editorFor

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have a div that looks like this,

```
<div class="row">
       @Html.LabelFor(job => j.serialNumber, "Serial Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-4">
           @Html.EditorFor(job => j.serialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = true} })
           <input id="edit@(j.serialNumber)" type="button" class="noprint btn btn-primary" value="Edit" onclick="enableEdit('@(j.serialNumber)')" />                                
       </div>        
</div>
```

This produces

[image: UI]

How can I make it so that the edit button goes, preferably in the editorFor textBox, or if that is not possible, on the very right of the box rather than the bottom?

Comment: `.row{display:flex;}` would do a trick for you.

Comment: That didn't do anything for me unfortunately @Manjuboyz

Comment: you need the label, textbox and button in the same line right?

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yes. I added what you suggested but it still positioned the button below the textbox

Comment: since it is C#(MVC) I cannot use same dynamic variables here, so hardcoded values. If this is not working then the issue is with something else.